# Why i am not able to connect Github desktop with VS Code? VS Code is only looking for Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github-desktop

1 : I have Installed github desktop on my system
 2 : Created my account on github - https://github.com/
 3 : Created a repository on github
 4 : checked for VS Code settings for Git enabled 
 5 : opened source control section

Here it does not show git or github icon

and asking me to download git not github desktop from git-scm.com/
 is there any difference in both

Comment: There’s a massive difference. One is a website, the other is the actual tool which keeps versions of source code.